# Olympiad polynomial problem with strange condition

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

This was a problem from an algebra handout, and I don’t know the exact source. Here it is:

Let $P(x)$ be a non constant polynomial with integer coefficients. Prove that there is no function $T$ from the set of integers to the set of integers such that the number of integers $y$ with $T^{n}(y)=y$ is equal to $P(n)$ for all positive integers $n$, where $T^{n}$ denotes the $n$-fold application of $T$.

I’ve thought about this question but I still have not one single idea. Hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from IMO Shortlist 2009.

**Hint 1:** For any function $T: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, let $S_T(n) $ be the number of solutions to $T^n(y) = y$.
Break up the image of $T$ into various cycles. Suppose that there are $C_T(n)$ (non-negative integer) cycles of length $n$.
Show that $S_T(n) = \sum_{k\mid n} kC_T(n)$.
There is at least one solution where this is the only fact about $T$ that we need.

**Hint 2:** For poylnomials with integer coefficients, $a-b \mid P(a) - P(b)$.
There is at least one solution where this is the only fact about integer-coefficient polynomials that we need.

**Hint 3:** A polynomial is non-constant iff $P(x) = k$ has finitely many solutions for any $k$.
There is at least one solution where this is the only fact about non-constant polynomials that we need.

**Corollary:** Show that if $P(n)= S_T(n)$, then it is a constant.
(This requires some work.) There are several ways to do this.
Without giving too much away, you don't have much options other than looking at terms like $P(0), P(1), P(p), P(pq), P(p^2), P(p^2q), P(p^k) \ldots$ for distinct primes $p, q$.

For example, (I don't think these statements are that helpful in the proof, but it gives you an idea of how they can be used.)

- $p-1 \mid P(p) - P(1)  = pC_T(p)\Rightarrow p-1 \mid C_T(p)$
- $ P(0) \equiv  P(p)  = C_T(1) + pC_T(p) \equiv C_T(1) = P(1) \pmod{p}$.    Hence conclude that $P(0) = P(1)$.

This is how I did it (which I think is distinct from their solutions.)

> $ q\mid P(pq) - P(0)$ from Hint 2

> $ q\mid P(pq) - P(p) = qC_T(q) + pq C_T(pq) $ from Hint 1

> So $q \mid P(p) - P(0)$

> Thus $P(p) = P(0)$ for all primes $p$, so $P(n)$ is the constant polynomial by Hint 3.